# UTMs on cross-domain and send to Salesforce using GTM

Tags: salesforce, google-tag-manager, salesforce-lightning, utm

PLEASE, Can someone help me out?

I have 1 domain and 1 subdomain and I have already done the cross-domain between them on google tag manager, but I need to push the UTMs from the main domain to the URLs on the subdomain where the "conversion" happens in order for my Lead enter on salesforce with those parameters. Also, if there's a way to push those UTMs besides from the URL to Salesforce between different domains, would be great too! I just want for those UTMs from the 1st domain to enter on Salesforce correctly.

I have already tried the 1st party cookie technique, but when I change domains it disappears and I have also tried with a script from an article on analytics mania about tracking UTMS between different domains, but nothing has worked out.

I really appreciate some help here.

Thank you so much in advanced!

Comment: it is not clear what happens, could you give an example, pls? furthermore, the cross-domain works automatically between domain and subdomain (with cookieDomain: auto)

Comment: Sure. So basically when I change pages the UTMs naturally disappear and I want to add them on the URL at the page where the conversion happens which is on a subdomain in order for the UTMs enter on Salesforce since is taking the UTMs from the URL of the conversion page. IF there's another way to push the UTMs to Salesforce beside putting them back on the URL of the convertion page, great to. I just want for the UTMs to be pushed to the Salesforce.